# Load changes in Sublime automatically when changes made externally

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have SASS file in Sublime and in another window I have opened the output CSS file.
I will give a demo to my colleagues where I will make changes to SASS file and on SAVE, I want the CSS file to load the changes automatically. At the moment I have to click the CSS file window (focus it) to see the changes. Is there any option which will make Sublime to load the changes automatically?

Comment: You can run the SASS compiler in something like `watch` mode, so that it keeps compiling whenever any change is being made to the SASS file. ST will reload the CSS file if it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `sass` command in `--watch` mode.

```
$ sass --watch input.scss:output.css # for a single file
$ sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets # for a whole directory
```

This way, whenever you make a change to your SASS file, it'll be compiled and the CSS file will be changed. SublineText will automatically reload the file if it changes.

Comment: I am doing this already. The css file is generated automatically but Sublime2 is not loading it automatically, I have to click/focus the css window to see the changes.

Comment: @AamirAfridi oh. got it. That's strange. Lemme check it out.

Comment: Basically I have two tabs. scss and css files are opened in it. I detached the css tab and moved it to the other screen. So when save scss file, I want css to show the changes straight away without clicking anywhere on the css tab to see the changes.